# Webpack html-loader error processing href in anchor tags

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-html-loader

Has anyone gotten Webpack/html-loader to handle image references in anchor tags (href attribute)?  I'm using the following webpack config that throws the error "Callback was already called" when the commented line below is included:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
    mode: devMode ? "development" : "production",
    entry: {
        index: "./src/js/pages/index.js",
        contact: "./src/js/pages/contact.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
            jQuery: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
            'window.jQuery': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
            Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/contact.shtml",
            filename: "contact.shtml",
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['contact']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.shtml",
            filename: "index.shtml",
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['index']
        }), 
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? "css/[name].css" : "css/[name].[hash].css",
            chunkFilename: devMode ? "[id].css" : "[id].[hash].css",
            publicPath: '../'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: devMode
            })
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: { loader: "babel-loader", options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] } }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    attributes: {
                        list: [
                            { tag: 'img', attribute: 'src', type: 'src' },
                            { tag: 'link', attribute: 'href', type: 'src' },
                            // { tag: 'a', attribute: 'href', type: 'src' } <--- throws error when included
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../',
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            publicPath: "../fonts",
                            outputPath: "./fonts",
                            emitFile: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(php)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            emitFile: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: 'images/',
                            emitFile: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    }
};
```

When the above line is commented out as displayed, everything compiles and  tags are properly handled, but the  tags are missing their images.

These are the relevant package versions I'm using:

- webpack: 4.43.0
- html-loader: 1.1.0
- file-loader: 6.0.0