# How can I work with anchor tags in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

I must be missing something because there seems to be almost no documentation about parsing anchor tags in webpack. For example if I want to hash the name of html files which are linked to in my landing index page.

Just like this post says:
[Webpack html-loader error processing href in anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618178/webpack-html-loader-error-processing-href-in-anchor-tags). Even if I attempt to extend the supported tags in html-loader it results in errors. Here is the documentation about extending supported tags: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#list.

So what is so special about anchor>href tags?

Answer (score 1):

The example post you linked isn't using the spread (...) operator, which may be part of the issue if you're only trying to **add** sources instead of define a limited number of sources -- if you're specifically getting errors with other file types not being managed.

From the config file I created today, which works with anchor `href`s:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|svg|png|pdf|gif)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        options: {
          sources: {
            list: [
              // All default supported tags and attributes
              "...",
              {
                tag: "a",
                attribute: "href",
                type: "src",
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ], 
  }
```

Without the "..." in the list: array above, webpack **replaces** its sources with those listed instead of **adding** the new sources to the existing list.

I am specifically using this config to grab a PDF asset in my src/ folder from an anchor tag in my HTML, copy it to dist/ and update its `href` in the final build, and this is working correctly for me.

Comment: Thanks, it is grabbing anchor tags now, I'm not sure exactly what I was missing, maybe webpack was updated or maybe it was the spread operator, I'm not sure.
However the emitted HTML is garbage despite I can hash the filename I am getting garbage javascript appended to the beginning of the HTML.

Comment: I did see that a .pdf file does work fine.
FYI in conjunction with HTML-Webpack-Plugin to get the path updated.